# How to validate an Azure AD B2C token generated by a daemon application in an Azure Http-triggered Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

I was able to successfully obtain a token by [this tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) in the daemon application but I am unable to verify it in my Azure HTTP-triggered function. That's despite the token is verified in the ASP.NET Core Web API whose code is in the repository.

Technically the token verification routine would look like the following snippet in the http-triggered function but the problem is that I don't know what the exact URL of `{authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration` should be.

```cs
ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager =
                new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                    $"{authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                    new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = null;
            config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

            ISecurityTokenValidator tokenValidator = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            // Initialize the token validation parameters
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // App Id URI and AppId of this service application are both valid audiences.
                ValidAudiences = new[] { audience, clientID },

                // Support Azure AD V1 and V2 endpoints.
                ValidIssuers = validIssuers,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys
            };

            try
            {
                SecurityToken securityToken;
                var claimsPrincipal = tokenValidator.ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out securityToken);
                return claimsPrincipal;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex.ToString());
            }
```

[This section](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi#todolist-web-api-code) of the document elaborates token validation in asp.net core web apps but there's no hint or advice on functions. Any guidance on configuration or code changes? Can we not use Microsoft Identity Web in azure http-triggered function apps?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://damienbod.com/2020/09/24/securing-azure-functions-using-azure-ad-jwt-bearer-token-authentication-for-user-access-tokens/) shares the approach. For daemon-generated tokens, we need though to substitute the `oidcWellknownEndpoints.Issuer` in `TokenValidationParameters` object instance with the following entry to make the token validation process pass successfully:

```
https://sts.windows.net/6b4744d0-705c-467f-a373-10c87c9bdd2c/
```